# How to remove duplicate break lines with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how could I remove duplicate break lines with PHP considering that the input can be from various OS.

Input Ex.: "02 02 02 02 \r\n\r\n 02 02 02 02 \r\n 02 02 02 02"

Input Ex.: "02 02 02 02 \n\n\n 02 02 02 02 \n\n 02 02 02 02"

Output Ex.: "02 02 02 02 \n 02 02 02 02 \n 02 02 02 02"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$s = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $s);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/jrgYG)

Answer (score 8):

More quickly is to replace only 2+ line breaks :) :

```
$s = preg_replace("/([\r\n]{4,}|[\n]{2,}|[\r]{2,})/", "\n", $s);
```